# TypeScript module augmentation across multiple modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs

I'm attempting to modify the prototype of an object inside another module (similar to as demonstrated [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)). However, module augmentation seems to only work when augmenting an object declared in a required file in the same module rather than another module.

For example, I have a class, `TestClass`:

```
// some-module/TestClass.ts

export class TestClass {
    someValue: string = "hi";
    someFunc(): number {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

And in the same module, I have this:

```
// some-module/index.ts

import { TestClass } from "./TestClass";

declare module "./TestClass" {
    interface TestClass {
        doSomethingElse(): void;
    }
}

TestClass.prototype.doSomethingElse = function(): void {
    console.log("Something else");
};
```

This works fine. However, if I move `TestClass` to another module (`test-module/TestClass.ts`) and modify the code appropriately like this, it gives me the error `'TestClass' only refers to a type, but being used as a value here.` whenever I try and access `TestClass`.

```
// some-module/index.ts

import { TestClass } from "test-project";

declare module "test-project" {
    interface TestClass {
        doSomethingElse(): void;
    }
}

TestClass.prototype.doSomethingElse = function(): void {
    console.log("Something else");
};
```

I'm using NodeJS module resolution with CommonJS.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't get what your code snippet with `import ... from "test-project";` is supposed to show. Is that the code you try to run after "[you] move `TestClass` to another module"? If so then why do you import `test-project` instead of `test-module/TestClass`? If not, please clarify.

Comment: Would you please give us a glimpse on your `test-module/index.ts `?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you need to import the whole module with import * instead of just the class you need, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9015